# Fill the gaps for a date range - SQL

Tags: sql

I have a problem mentioned below and cant do it without SQL as I have 2 million rows.

I have a table `Table1` where I have item/loc with promoted prices for the given date range. Also I have another table  `Table 2` where I have the base price for each item/loc from 2015 - 2017 which I must use to fill the gaps given in table1

**Table1**:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Item  | Location | Startdate | EndDate   | Promoted Price |
+-------+----------+-----------+-----------+----------------+
| Item1 | Loc1     | 6/23/2015 | 6/24/2015 | 22             |
| Item1 | Loc1     | 7/10/2015 | 7/17/2015 | 30             |
| Item1 | Loc1     | 7/24/2015 | 7/31/2015 | 30             |
| Item2 | Loc2     | 6/21/2015 | 8/7/2015  | 25             |
| Item2 | Loc2     | 8/28/2015 | 9/4/2015  | 27             |
| Item2 | Loc2     | 9/11/2015 | 9/18/2015 | 28             |
+-------+----------+-----------+-----------+----------------+
```

**Table2**

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Item  | Location | Startdate | EndDate    | Full_Price |
+-------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+
| Item1 | Loc1     | 1/1/2015  | 12/31/2017 | 32         |
| Item2 | Loc2     | 1/1/2015  | 12/31/2017 | 24         |
| Item3 | Loc3     | 1/1/2015  | 12/31/2017 | 54         |
| Item4 | Loc4     | 1/1/2015  | 12/31/2017 | 67         |
| Item5 | Loc5     | 1/1/2015  | 12/31/2017 | 39         |
| Item6 | Loc6     | 1/1/2015  | 12/31/2017 | 48         |
| Item7 | Loc7     | 1/1/2015  | 12/31/2017 | 63         |
| Item8 | Loc8     | 1/1/2015  | 12/31/2017 | 52         |
| Item9 | Loc9     | 1/1/2015  | 12/31/2017 | 51         |
+-------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

Result should be like this:

```
| Item  | Location | Startdate | EndDate   | Promoted Price |
+-------+----------+-----------+-----------+----------------+
| Item1 |   Loc1   | 6/23/2015 | 6/24/2015 | 22             |
| Item1 |   Loc1   | 6/25/2015 | 7/9/2015  | 32             |
| Item1 |   Loc1   | 7/10/2015 | 7/17/2015 | 30             |
| Item1 | Loc1     | 7/18/2015 | 7/23/2015 | 32             |
| Item1 | Loc1     | 7/24/2015 | 7/31/2015 | 30             |
```

Answer (score 0):

what gaps? it looks like you filtering for "Item1" and "Loc1"

Comment: Hi Jesse, I you can see row 1 & 2 for first table (table1) . I need to create a new record from startdate date 6/25/2015 till 7/09/2015 and for this record i need to take value from table 2 which is the default value for the gaps (records missing for the some dates)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I was able to resolve this problem by using Lead() function.